# jQuery UI don't work for firefox 3.6

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, accordion, firefox3.6

I try to get run jQuery, especially jQuery UI on Firefox 3.6. I know it is a pretty old browser - but you know how customers are.

**On version 4 it works fine, but v3.6 handle it as wouldn't be their any scripts.**

The website includes the accordion and tabs feature too.

Do you have any experiences with jQuery 1.9.1 and UI 1.9.2 on Firefox 3.6?

Thanks a lot,
Paul

Comment: I can imagine a customer insisting that you support IE8, because it's as far as you can take IE on WinXP. There's no reason whatsoever to continue to support old Firefox, however. My approach would be to sell that philosophy. Best of luck.

Comment: Firefox 3.6? Seriously? Is the customer still using their 1000 free hours of AOL internet too? Supporting a few major versions back is one thing, but you're talking about what, 25 major versions behind?

Comment: I know… I sent them your appropriate comments, maybe it helps.

Comment: @PatrickQ Firefox 3 isn't the right target for a website, but it may be the best simple GUI platform available on a workstation such as the still-supported RHEL5. Dealing with old jQuery is arguably far easier than dealing with old Qt, Tk, or trying to build new browsers to deploy on old systems which prioritize stability over progress because, industry.